# Not able to listen to public events in Laravel + ReactJs + Soketi

Tags: reactjs, pusher, laravel-echo, pusher-js, laravel-broadcast

I've been trying to implement a chat application that can listen to a NewMessage event in my backend which is in Laravel and I want to read these events in my Frontend which is a vite-react-app.

I have a [soketi](https://docs.soketi.app) docker image running in my localhost with this command:

`docker run -p 6001:6001 -p 9601:9601 quay.io/soketi/soketi:1.4-16-debian`

Chat application is using **pusher-php-server**, **soketi** , **Laravel (backend)**, **ReactJs (frontend)** with **Pusher-js** and **Laravel-Echo**.

**Backend** :

- The route for triggering a test event in the backend =

`Route::post('testMessage', [ChatController::class, 'testMessage']);`

- The ChatController class =

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Events\NewMessage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
    public function testMessage()
    {
        logger('chatController => testMessage triggered');
        $message = 'this is a test message';
        broadcast(new NewMessage($message));
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Test message sent successfully']);
    }
}
```

- An NewMessage Event =

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Chat;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public string $message;

    public function __construct(string $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        logger('NewMessage Event Triggered. Message = ' . $this->message);
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new Channel('public'),
            new PrivateChannel('private')
        ];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'new.message';
    }
}
```

- Broadcasting.php file =

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST') ?: 'api-' . env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1') . '.pusher.com',
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],
```

- .env file (pusher config) =

```
# pusher config
PUSHER_APP_ID=app-id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=app-key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=app-secret
PUSHER_HOST=1270.0.1
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
```

- channels.php =

```
// public chat channel
Broadcast::channel('public', function () {
    return true;
});
```

**Frontend**:

- Here I'm trying to listen to the NewMessasge Event on a demo CRA on the same local system with this code:

```
// Laravel-echo
  var echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "pusher",
    cluster: "mt1",
    key: "app-key",
    wsHost: "127.0.0.1",
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
  });

  // pusher
  var client = new PusherJs("app-key", {
    wsHost: "127.0.0.1",
    wsPort: 6001,
    cluster: "mt1",
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted: false,
    enableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
  });



  useEffect(() => {
    let count = 1;

    const channel = echo.channel("public");
    console.log('Laravel-echo subscribed = ', channel);

    channel.listen("new.message", (e) => {

      console.log("New Message Event Occurred ....");
      console.log(e);

      setMessageEventCount(count);
      count++;

    });
  }, []);



  useEffect(() => {
    let count = 1;

    const channel = client.subscribe('public');
    console.log('Pusher subscribed = ', channel);

    channel.bind('new.message', (e) => {

      console.log('New Message Event Occurred ....');
      console.log(e);

      setMessageEventCount(count);
      count++;

    })
  }, []);
```

I've tried listening to the event using both Laravel-echo and Pusher-js. But no luck.

The frontend is connecting to the 'public' channel in both the cases (echo and pusher). But the events are not getting triggered/listened to my frontend.

Comment: SOLUTION: Redis Queue, the redis queue was not running because of which the events were not getting triggered or listened. I used this command to run queue: `php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default`

Comment: Please don't add thing like "SOLVED" to a question title. If you managed to solve your own problem, post an **answer** describing the solution in detail, and accept it after the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Redis Queue was not running because of which the events were not getting triggered or listened. I used this command to run queue: `php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default`

Answer (score 0):

Anyone stumbling accros this issue and not being able to solve it with this... This might be another solution you (or at least I) didn't think of:
If you use Soketi in combination with Laravel Echo (and in my case in VueJS), make sure the default Soketi vars are set correctly, in my case for example:

```
SOKETI_DEFAULT_APP_KEY=MyAppKey
SOKETI_DEFAULT_APP_ID=MyAppId
SOKETI_DEFAULT_APP_SECRET=MyAppSecret
```

Make sure these vars are the same as the vars in **PUSHER_***